# Add vector on vector's tip and rotation

Tags: linear-algebra

Vector $v_1=[3,3,3],v_2=[1,0,0]$;

I mean adding vector upon vector with it's direction.
Like $v1+v2$ wouldn't be $[4,3,3]$ but $[4,4,4]$.

Or another example $[1,2,0]+[0,3,0]$ will be around $[3,0,0]$.
I don't know math very good but in my head I can explain it as "add vector upon vector on it's rotation/direction".

The question: How to add vector upon vector on it's direction?

Here is a picture for explain my question even better:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0xsB.png

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche How to add vector upon vector on it's direction. edited.

Comment: I don't see how your "addition" works. Can you give a picture or explanation of what exactly you want add?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to describe complex multiplication in $3$ dimensions. There, if we multiply $z_1,z_2$, the magnitude is the product of the magnitudes, while the angle is the sum of the angles (so long as $z_1,z_2\neq0$). Am I correct?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yeah, I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to add the length of the second vector to the first one, correct? In this case you have

$$u+|v|(u/|u|)$$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the norm, i.e., $|u|=\sqrt{u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2}$.

Comment: No... I knew that's wasn't good example... It's adding vector on vector's tip and rotate that vector to the second's rotate. But in 3D.

Comment: Ok, then compute the length $a=|u+v|$; the vector you want is then $av/|v|$.